# How to Record Both Mic Audio and Speakers while using headset

Tags: mac, audio, speakers, microphone, audio-recording

I'm trying to record my screen with sound at the same time, but right now, my jack stopped working (it's with the red light) and I have to use a headset so that I can have sound on my Mac.

So my question is: Can I record my screen, my audio input (me babbling) and the supposed audio output that should come from speakers (that now its coming out from my headset).

Is there a way, Or is it just impossible?

Comment: It was a huge hassle for me to figure this out. Here is a free way on Mac to record audio from your mic and what is playing through your speakers simultaneously (but not your screen): https://superuser.com/a/1426622/74576 When I want the screen too, I replace QuickTime with OBS, which is also free.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### ScreenFlow

Check the Record Computer Audio checkbox and change the input device to the microphone or headset:

[image]

### QuickTime Player (option 1)

1. Install [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/).
2. Open Audio Midi Setup, create an aggregate device, and check Built-in Microphone and Soundflower (2ch):

   [image]
3. Create a multi-output device and check Soundflower (2ch). If you want to hear the audio while you're recording it, also check Built-in Output.

   [image]
4. Set the default output device to the multi-output device from System Preferences.
5. Select New Screen Recording in QuickTime Player, set the input to the aggregate device, and keep the volume slider at zero.

   [image]
6. Start recording.

### QuickTime Player (option 2)

1. Install [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/).
2. Change the output device to Soundflower (2ch) from System Preferences:

   [image]
3. Create a new project in GarageBand.
4. Change the output device to Soundflower (2ch):

   [image]
5. Set monitor to on:

   [image]
6. Select New Screen Recording in QuickTime Player, set the input to Soundflower (2ch), and keep the volume slider at zero.

   [image]
7. Start recording.

If you want to hear the audio while you're recording it, use Soundflowerbed:

[image]

Comment: soundflower is now working with yosemite too

Comment: Just did QuickTime Player (option 1) on Sierra. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Not sure if the suggestion from @Arash works. The video goes into another possible software which has a limited-time free option. 

tl;dr - no such option exists for free.